# Resizing Geometries/GeometryDrawings

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry, visualization, resize

I'm drawing some primitives in Geometry form ("F1 M 77,92L 704,92L 704,517L 77,517L 77,92 Z" i.e.), storing them in GeometryDrawings and displaying by use of DrawingVisuals and object inherited from FrameworkElement. Everything was smooth so far, but now there is a need to **resize** some geometries manually. By that i mean entering new height/width value and get new coordinates not using *Transforms*. BoundingBox of geometry is readonly, and changing size of respective visualization object with content set to stretch is not an option because state (new data) won't be maintained in resulting (geometry) serialization xaml. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used transform along with few normalizations and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is likely the built-in ViewBox Container which by definition:

> Defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.

[Overview on wpftutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html)

Comment: Transform can be applied into Geometry itself, but that's not what i need. I think I can do some workaround like take new desired size of geometry, take bounding box of source element, divide one on another, take coefficient, apply ScaleTransform, but that may cause performance issues and other side effects. I've dug deeper into WPF graphics stack and found out about Figures, maybe they can help me to achieve wanted result. The problem is i get source geometry in Path form (Expression Design export) and i guess Segments structure cannot be restored from this data.